# How can i get the info of container created by kubernetes as types.StatsJSON from docker golang client?

Tags: docker, go

Code in the file [github.com/docker/docker/client/container_stats.go](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/890231f46beb9d48a2f1307c83cee48c2245339b/client/container_stats.go) shows 2 ways to get container info, `client.ContainerStats` and `client.ContainerStatsOneShot`.
But the results both are `types.ContainerStats`, which doesn't include network info.
How can i get the `types.StatsJSON` of a container with the Docker Go client library?

```golang
type StatsJSON struct {
    Stats

    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    ID   string `json:"id,omitempty"`

    // Networks request version >=1.21
    Networks map[string]NetworkStats `json:"networks,omitempty"`
}
```

```
func main() {
cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
containers, err := cli.ContainerList(context.Background(), types.ContainerListOptions{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, container := range containers {
    containerStats, err := cli.ContainerStats(context.Background(), container.ID, false)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(containerStats)
    fmt.Println(containerStats.Body)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    buf.ReadFrom(containerStats.Body)
    newStr := buf.String()
    fmt.Printf(newStr)
}
```

}

my code is shown above.

I found that if the container is created by kubernetes, the code can't get the network info.

```
{"read":"2022-04-16T13:19:35.763484238Z","preread":"2022-04-16T13:19:34.758939054Z","pids_stats":{"current":2},"blkio_stats":{"io_service_bytes_recursive":[],"io_serviced_recursive":[],"io_queue_recursive":[],"io_service_time_recursive":[],"io_wait_time_recursive":[],"io_merged_recursive":[],"io_time_recursive":[],"sectors_recursive":[]},"num_procs":0,"storage_stats":{},"cpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":81301483,"percpu_usage":[0,381774,697871,3974768,0,49920,599904,622885,6274012,858410,0,570611,52635,11229798,100631,0,99914,0,479666,698862,51132727,902108,1941742,633245,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"usage_in_kernelmode":40000000,"usage_in_usermode":20000000},"system_cpu_usage":82393060580000000,"online_cpus":24,"throttling_data":{"periods":12,"throttled_periods":8,"throttled_time":811771919}},"precpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":81301483,"percpu_usage":[0,381774,697871,3974768,0,49920,599904,622885,6274012,858410,0,570611,52635,11229798,100631,0,99914,0,479666,698862,51132727,902108,1941742,633245,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"usage_in_kernelmode":40000000,"usage_in_usermode":20000000},"system_cpu_usage":82393036780000000,"online_cpus":24,"throttling_data":{"periods":12,"throttled_periods":8,"throttled_time":811771919}},"memory_stats":{"usage":1515520,"max_usage":7999488,"stats":{"active_anon":196608,"active_file":0,"cache":0,"dirty":0,"hierarchical_memory_limit":419430400,"hierarchical_memsw_limit":0,"inactive_anon":0,"inactive_file":0,"mapped_file":0,"pgfault":2077,"pgmajfault":0,"pgpgin":1658,"pgpgout":1610,"rss":196608,"rss_huge":0,"total_active_anon":196608,"total_active_file":0,"total_cache":0,"total_dirty":0,"total_inactive_anon":0,"total_inactive_file":0,"total_mapped_file":0,"total_pgfault":2077,"total_pgmajfault":0,"total_pgpgin":1658,"total_pgpgout":1610,"total_rss":196608,"total_rss_huge":0,"total_unevictable":0,"total_writeback":0,"unevictable":0,"writeback":0},"limit":419430400},"name":"/k8s_centos_ltstatefulset-b-0_default_19f13fc1-b971-47c0-9519-619b64c01b68_195","id":"b15626bfc4665c457c7fb319f17e162d611262d193e38ec9e7878ca8b3e8b02b"}
```

if not, the code works.

```
{"read":"2022-04-16T14:35:12.97263525Z","preread":"2022-04-16T14:35:11.937969083Z","pids_stats":{"current":25},"blkio_stats":{"io_service_bytes_recursive":[{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Read","value":11210752},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Write","value":8192},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Sync","value":4096},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Async","value":11214848},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Total","value":11218944}],"io_serviced_recursive":[{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Read","value":527},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Write","value":2},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Sync","value":1},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Async","value":528},{"major":8,"minor":0,"op":"Total","value":529}],"io_queue_recursive":[],"io_service_time_recursive":[],"io_wait_time_recursive":[],"io_merged_recursive":[],"io_time_recursive":[],"sectors_recursive":[]},"num_procs":0,"storage_stats":{},"cpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":349863146,"percpu_usage":[10474676,1510192,454233,1388678,254249,80111,3389261,101473612,416604,8936772,5378206,4940434,0,347495,891133,85645,0,0,168781006,13378842,9622376,4594553,9938770,3526298],"usage_in_kernelmode":80000000,"usage_in_usermode":260000000},"system_cpu_usage":109879214590000000,"online_cpus":24,"throttling_data":{"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}},"precpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":349863146,"percpu_usage":[10474676,1510192,454233,1388678,254249,80111,3389261,101473612,416604,8936772,5378206,4940434,0,347495,891133,85645,0,0,168781006,13378842,9622376,4594553,9938770,3526298],"usage_in_kernelmode":80000000,"usage_in_usermode":260000000},"system_cpu_usage":109879190530000000,"online_cpus":24,"throttling_data":{"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}},"memory_stats":{"usage":33136640,"max_usage":34250752,"stats":{"active_anon":15036416,"active_file":4644864,"cache":11415552,"dirty":0,"hierarchical_memory_limit":9223372036854771712,"hierarchical_memsw_limit":0,"inactive_anon":4096,"inactive_file":6766592,"mapped_file":5271552,"pgfault":9844,"pgmajfault":77,"pgpgin":9350,"pgpgout":2892,"rss":15036416,"rss_huge":0,"total_active_anon":15036416,"total_active_file":4644864,"total_cache":11415552,"total_dirty":0,"total_inactive_anon":4096,"total_inactive_file":6766592,"total_mapped_file":5271552,"total_pgfault":9844,"total_pgmajfault":77,"total_pgpgin":9350,"total_pgpgout":2892,"total_rss":15036416,"total_rss_huge":0,"total_unevictable":0,"total_writeback":0,"unevictable":0,"writeback":0},"limit":50609074176},"name":"/mynginx","id":"4af194a6885917eed220a0c45a235e749b566bd5aa0ab18ae5aaf5c6295fc527","networks":{"eth0":{"rx_bytes":3385,"rx_packets":47,"rx_errors":0,"rx_dropped":1,"tx_bytes":0,"tx_packets":0,"tx_errors":0,"tx_dropped":0}}}
```

How can i get the network info of the container created by k8s?

Comment: I think it should be a problem with the docker version, i can get the network info in Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57, and failed in Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350. The struct shows 'Networks request version >=1.21', what does the 1.21 means?

Comment: I just found that, if the container is created by kubernetes, the code can't get the network info, if not, the code works.

Comment: You keep changing the requirements of your question. I mean in regard if your initial question my answer may have been correct or at least relevant. Slowly but surely this is morphing into a completely separate issue.

Comment: If it's running in Kubernetes, you shouldn't (and probably can't) use the Docker API to inspect or manage it.  When you get up to the point of running pods/containers you should generally think of Docker and Kubernetes as two totally separate things.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the body since `ContainerStats` returns the data in a field named body which is an [io.ReadCloser](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadCloser).

```
type ContainerStats struct {
    Body   io.ReadCloser `json:"body"`
    OSType string        `json:"ostype"`
}
```

The below code works as expected. I can decode the data from the body into a `StatsJSON` struct and access the `Networks` fields.

```
// create a client
cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// get some container stats
cs, err := cli.ContainerStats(context.TODO(), "<container id>", false)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// dont forget to close the body
defer cs.Body.Close()

// decode the body into a StatsJSON struct
data := types.StatsJSON{}
err = json.NewDecoder(cs.Body).Decode(&data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// access the Networks field
fmt.Println(data.Networks)
```